# if-countif more than 7

Tags: excel, vba

I have a little problem on a excel file . i use the formula below in the purpose to :

the function returns a value if the cell selected contains another value (string). this work perfectly . BUT i have 20 if/countif to add and it doesnt work cause i cant get over 7...
Any idea to solve that problem easily ? 
I give you also the vba code under the excel code ...

Thanks a lot for helping

```
=SI(NB.SI([@[ENTRY_LABEL]];"*MAZ*");"MAZ";SI(NB.SI([@[ENTRY_LABEL]];"*MGN*");"MGN";SI(NB.SI([@[ENTRY_LABEL]];"*Magnitude*");"MGN";SI(NB.SI([@[ENTRY_LABEL]];"*AJU*");"AJU";SI(NB.SI([@[ENTRY_LABEL]];"*Reclas*");"Reclass";"")))))
```

VBA code:

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(Tableau4[[#This Row],[ENTRY_LABEL]],""*MAZ*""),""MAZ"",IF(COUNTIF(Tableau4[[#This Row],[ENTRY_LABEL]],""*MGN*""),""MGN"",IF(COUNTIF(Tableau4[[#This Row],[ENTRY_LABEL]],""*Magnitude*""),""MGN"",IF(COUNTIF(Tableau4[[#This Row],[ENTRY_LABEL]],""*AJU*""),""AJU"",IF(COUNTIF(Tableau4[[#This Row],[ENTRY_LABEL]],""*Reclas*""),""Reclass"","""")))))"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you may use a VBA formula. Simply write something like this in the Visual Basic Editor, in the module level:

```
Public Function many_ifs(my_cell As Range) As String

Select Case my_cell.Value

    Case 1
        many_ifs = "one"

    Case 2
        many_ifs = "two"

    Case 3
        many_ifs = "three"

    Case 4
        many_ifs = "four"

    Case Else:
        many_ifs = "Unknown"

End Select

End Function
```

Then call it from Excel as a normal formula like this:

[image]

Here is how to get started with VBA:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thank you as well! Glad to see that you manage to fix the formula in your own way! :)

Comment: @Vityata excuse for my edit, but just to make it cleaner and shorter

Comment: it wasnt tough to fix, i just needed to know the method to applicate ;) i used this and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I finally used this and it works.

```
Public Function cat1_0lia(my_cell As Range) As String

    Dim result  As String

    Select Case True

    Case my_cell.Value Like "*MAZ*":
    result = "MAZ"
    Case my_cell.Value Like "*Maz*":
    result = "MAZ"
    Case my_cell.Value Like "*maz*":
    result = "MAZ"
    Case my_cell.Value Like "*Mis à 0*":
    result = "MAZ"

    Case my_cell.Value Like "*Mgn*":
    result = "MGN"
    Case my_cell.Value Like "*MGN*":
    result = "MGN"
    Case my_cell.Value Like "*Magnitude*":
    result = "MGN"

    Case my_cell.Value Like "*AJU*":
    result = "AJU"
    Case my_cell.Value Like "*Aju*":
    result = "AJU"
    Case my_cell.Value Like "*aju*":
    result = "AJU"


    Case my_cell.Value Like "*RECLASS*":
    result = "RECLASS"
    Case my_cell.Value Like "*Reclass*":
    result = "RECLASS"
    Case my_cell.Value Like "*reclass*":
    result = "RECLASS"

    Case Else:
    result = ""


    End Select

    cat1_0lia = result

End Function
```